# How do I access the time at which WordPress refreshed RSS fetch_feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, simplepie

WordPress 6.4.2 running Twenty Twenty-Four theme.

I am able to control the refresh interval of a feed in a RSS Block using a code snippet without any problem:

```
function return_cache_time( $seconds )
{
// change the default feed cache recreation period to 10 minutes
return (int) 600;
}

// adds the filter to set cache lifetime
add_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_600' );

$feed = fetch_feed( $feed_url );

// remove the filter to reset the cache lifetime to default value
remove_filter( 'wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime' , 'return_cache_time' );
```

I now want to record the *actual time that the refresh took place* (as a shortcode so I can put it on the page next to the Block).

Looking for suggestions as to how this might be achieved?

Thoughts: Not tried anything yet as I have no idea where to start but AFAIK WordPress does not consider a page as modified when only the RSS is refreshed. I think the answer may have something to do with SimplePie.

Comment: you can get the real-time using `current_time( 'mysql' )`
Also can use the `do_feed_{$feed}` hook to record the time while the feed is loaded.
Check the documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_feed_feed/

Comment: Thank you that sounds promising. To be honest coding is not one of my skills. Would you be kind enough to elaborate in more detail with an example?